# Tensorflow process killed

Tags: tensorflow, keras

EDIT1: This is the output of `dmesg` after the process is killed.

```
[12011.054140] Out of memory: Killed process 472061 (python3) total-vm:98626268kB, anon-rss:22003964kB, file-rss:62584kB, shmem-rss:14336kB, UID:1000 pgtables:173776kB oom_score_adj:0
[12011.941128] oom_reaper: reaped process 472061 (python3), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:74732kB, shmem-rss:14336kB
```

I need to train 5 models each for 10 times using tensorflow and keras for a homework. 2 of the models are multilayer perceptron models and remaining 3 of them are CNN models. I am training using my GPU, GTX1660Ti. I have no issue training MLP models, but when I try to train the CNN models I get the error below:

[image]

I have added these two lines of code to solve this issue:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

However, when I try to train all of the models in a single script, my process gets killed after succesfully training 3 models:

[image]

Training dataset contains 27000 images, test dataset contains 5000 images, and validation dataset contains 3000 images each 28*28. I suspect gpu memory is the issue but I do not know the details. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it give any warnings before killing the process? *(like running out of memory)*

Comment: @Frightera no unfortunately. It kills it like in the last screenshot. Nothing before.